# Get Row with Max Date from a Union All

Tags: oracle, subquery, max, union

From the below query, I want to find the event with the last activity_dt for each request_id.  I have been working on this for hours, to no avail.  Can anyone help?

```
select a.event as event, a.activity_dt as activity_dt, b.request_id as request_id
from gs_pr_obl_event a, gs_pr_obl b
where a.obligation_id = b.obligation_id
union all
select event as event, activity_dt as activity_dt, request_id as request_id
from gs_pr_req_event;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
SELECT event, MAX(activity_dt), request_id
FROM(
     SELECT A.event AS event, A.activity_dt AS activity_dt, b.request_id AS request_id
     FROM gs_pr_obl_event A, gs_pr_obl b
     WHERE A.obligation_id = b.obligation_id
     UNION ALL
     SELECT event AS event, activity_dt AS activity_dt, request_id AS request_id
     FROM gs_pr_req_event
     )
GROUP BY event, request_id;
```